# When the pullback of a smooth function on germs is an isomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be a pair of smooth manifolds and let $ f\colon X\to Y $ be a smooth function between them.

Let $ a\in X $ and let $ f_a\colon \mathscr C_{Y,f(x)}^\infty\to \mathscr C_{X,x}^\infty $ be the pullback-of-$ f $ map between the $ \mathbb R $-algebras of smooth germs respectively on $ f(a) $ and on $ x $ that maps a germ $ g_f(a) $ in the germ $ (g\circ f)_a $.

It can happen that $ f_a $ is an isomorphism of $ \mathbb R $-algebras while $ f $ is not. For example, if $ X $ is an open subset of $ Y $ and $ f\colon X\hookrightarrow Y $ is the canonical embedding map.

I was wondering: Is it possible to say precisely under what conditions on $ f $ the map $ f_a $ is an isomorphism?